# Come/go in and out of

Tags: difference, idioms, prepositional-phrases

If someone keeps entering and exiting my bedroom, and I want him to stop. Should I say:

- don’t come in and out of my bedroom.

Or

- don’t go in and out of my bedroom.

Is this just a case of directional difference between the verbs ‘come’ and ‘go’, or is it that only one of them fits as part of an idiomatic construction?

Also, apart from ‘in and out’, are there any other expressions/phrases that can express the same idea succinctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think both are fine - if you are saying this to him inside your bedroom, it's come, if you're outside, it's more likely to be go. That said, if you are generally in there when he comes in, you might also use 'come' even if you're discussing it outside...

I may be missing the point here but given that you can only exit once you have entered I'd go for 'please keep out of my bedroom'.